# Amazon ECS API to fetch 1000 top selling books

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I need the API to fetch the top selling books on Amazon. By default [it only fetches the top 10 items](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/index.html?RG_TopSellers.html), but I need more than 10, near about 1000 items content by using single hit.

**OR**

I need the way to scrape the 1000 top selling books using the Amazon ECS API.

**OR**

Is there any way except the Amazon API to scrape all of the top selling books on Amazon?

Comment: Your question title says "100" (10^2) but your question text says "1000" (10^3).  Please correct whichever is inaccurate.

Comment: I think both the title and the text says 1000.

Comment: Look at the edit history.  You're responding to a comment that's over 18 months old and things have changed since it was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how I do it - but it won't work for more than 100 items after the end of this month as Amazon are limiting ItemPage to 10.

```
rescheck = Amazon::Ecs.item_search("search term here", :response_group => 'Large', :country => 'uk')
n=0
rescheck.total_pages.times do |n|
  n=n+1
  if n <= rescheck.total_pages
      res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search("search term here", :response_group => 'Large', :item_page =>n, :country => 'uk')
        res.items.each do |item|

          asin = item.get('ASIN')
          title = item.get('ItemAttributes/Title')
          brand = item.get('ItemAttributes/Brand')

 #etc
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the 100 bestselling books you have to specify the `ItemPage` parameter:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
Operation=ItemSearch&
BrowseNode=17&
SearchIndex=Books&
ItemPage=2
&Sort=salesrank
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

*Problem:* The maximum ItemPage number that can be returned is 10. So you cant get past 100 books.

Reference: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?ItemSearch.html

Comment: Actually I know how to pull the 10 items from the Amazon but I need a way to pull the 1000 items from the amazon.Is there any other way to pull it

Comment: @Only 100 for a specific search parameter.

Comment: I understand that only only 10 products can be returned per request, but how does one go about retrieving products 10-20, 20-30 and so on?

Comment: Just wanted to know whether `http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService...` is a free API or is it paid or is there a free limit? I want to use it to search for books using ISBN and Amazon does not let me create an API Key until I provide a Credit Card.

Comment: That should be the free api. I think, i haven't put the credit card info 18 mths back

Answer (score 0):

Using previous comment, I scrap from DOM of documentation for IN this categories:

```
   [  
   {  
      "index":"All",
      "node":""
   },
   {  
      "index":"Baby",
      "node":"1571275031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Beauty",
      "node":"1355017031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Books",
      "node":"976390031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Automotive",
      "node":"4772061031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Apparel",
      "node":"1571272031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"PCHardware",
      "node":"976393031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Electronics",
      "node":"976420031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"GiftCards",
      "node":"3704983031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Grocery",
      "node":"2454179031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"HealthPersonalCare",
      "node":"1350385031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"HomeGarden",
      "node":"2454176031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Industrial",
      "node":"5866079031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Jewelry",
      "node":"1951049031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"KindleStore",
      "node":"1571278031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Luggage",
      "node":"2454170031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"DVD",
      "node":"976417031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Music",
      "node":"976446031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"MusicalInstruments",
      "node":"3677698031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"OfficeProducts",
      "node":"2454173031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"PetSupplies",
      "node":"4740420031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Shoes",
      "node":"1571284031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Software",
      "node":"976452031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"SportingGoods",
      "node":"1984444031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Toys",
      "node":"1350381031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"VideoGames",
      "node":"976461031"
   },
   {  
      "index":"Watches",
      "node":"1350388031"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace MarcL;

use MarcL\CurlHttpRequest;
use MarcL\AmazonUrlBuilder;
use MarcL\Transformers\DataTransformerFactory;

class AmazonAPI
{
    private $urlBuilder = NULL;
    private $dataTransformer = NULL;
    public $item=0;
    public $perRequest=0;
    public function IND_money_format($money)
    {
        $len = strlen($money);
        $m = '';
        $money = strrev($money);
        for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
            if(( $i==3 || ($i>3 && ($i-1)%2==0) )&& $i!=$len){
                $m .=',';
            }
            $m .=$money[$i];
        }
        return strrev($m);
    }
    // Valid names that can be used for search
    private $mValidSearchNames = array(
        'All',
        'Apparel',
        'Appliances',
        'Automotive',
        'Baby',
        'Beauty',
        'Blended',
        'Books',
        'Classical',
        'DVD',
        'Electronics',
        'Grocery',
        'HealthPersonalCare',
        'HomeGarden',
        'HomeImprovement',
        'Jewelry',
        'KindleStore',
        'Kitchen',
        'Lighting',
        'Marketplace',
        'MP3Downloads',
        'Music',
        'MusicTracks',
        'MusicalInstruments',
        'OfficeProducts',
        'OutdoorLiving',
        'Outlet',
        'PetSupplies',
        'PCHardware',
        'Shoes',
        'Software',
        'SoftwareVideoGames',
        'SportingGoods',
        'Tools',
        'Toys',
        'VHS',
        'Video',
        'VideoGames',
        'Watches'
    );

    private $mErrors = array();

    public function __construct($urlBuilder, $outputType) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->dataTransformer = DataTransformerFactory::create($outputType);
    }

    public function GetValidSearchNames() {
        return $this->mValidSearchNames;
    }

    /**
     * Search for items
     *
     * @param   keywords            Keywords which we're requesting
     * @param   searchIndex         Name of search index (category) requested. NULL if searching all.
     * @param   sortBy              Category to sort by, only used if searchIndex is not 'All'
     * @param   condition           Condition of item. Valid conditions : Used, Collectible, Refurbished, All
     *
     * @return  mixed               SimpleXML object, array of data or false if failure.
     */
    public function ItemSearch($keywords,$itemPage, $searchIndex = NULL, $sortBy = NULL, $condition = 'All',$minPrice=50000,$maxPrice=55000) {
        ?>
        <table cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Title</td>
                    <td>List Price</td>
                    <td>Offer Price</td>
                    <td>Offer Selling Price</td>
                    <td>Amount Saved</td>
                    <td>Brand Name</td>
                    <td>Size</td>
                    <td>Color</td>
                    <td>Manufacturer</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
            <?php

        $totalPages=0;
        while($maxPrice<=100000)
        {
            $finished=false;
            $itemPage=0;
            while(!$finished)
            {
                $itemPage=$itemPage+1;
                sleep(1);
                $mer="MerchantId";
                $merVal="Amazon";
                $params = array(
                    'Operation' => 'ItemSearch',
                    'ResponseGroup' => 'Small,ItemAttributes,Offers,OfferSummary',
                    'Keywords' => $keywords,
                    'Condition' => $condition,
                    'ItemPage' => $itemPage,
                    'ListPrice' => $itemPage,
                    'MinimumPrice' => $minPrice,
                    'MaximumPrice' => $maxPrice,
                    'SearchIndex' => empty($searchIndex) ? 'All' : $searchIndex,
                    'Sort' => $sortBy && ($searchIndex != 'All') ? $sortBy : NULL
                );
                $totalPages=$this->FetchItems($params,$itemPage,$maxPrice,false);
                if(($itemPage)==1)
                {
                    $finished=true;
                    $itemPage=0;
                }
            }
            $minPrice=$maxPrice;
            $maxPrice=$maxPrice+5000;
        }
        //echo "<br/>total Records : ".$this->item;
        ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/><br/>

        <?php
        $style="";
                for($looper=1;$looper<=$totalPages;$looper++)
                {
                    if($looper>($itemPage-3) && $looper<($itemPage+3))
                    {
                        if($looper==$itemPage)
                        {
                            $style="style='color:red;'";
                            echo "<a href='examples.php?itemPage=".$looper."' ".$style.">".$looper."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "<a href='examples.php?itemPage=".$looper."'>".$looper."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                        }
                    }else if($looper>($totalPages-3))
                    {

                        echo "<a href='examples.php?itemPage=".$looper."'>".$looper."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }else if($looper>(($totalPages/2)-3) && $looper<(($totalPages/2)+3))
                    {

                        echo "<a href='examples.php?itemPage=".$looper."'>".$looper."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }
                }
        die();
        //return $this->MakeAndParseRequest($params,$itemPage);
    }

    /**
     * Lookup items from ASINs
     *
     * @param   asinList            Either a single ASIN or an array of ASINs
     * @param   onlyFromAmazon      True if only requesting items from Amazon and not 3rd party vendors
     *
     * @return  mixed               SimpleXML object, array of data or false if failure.
     */
    public function ItemLookup($asinList,$itemPage, $onlyFromAmazon = false) {
        $asinList="B01D0XDW1C";
        if (is_array($asinList)) {
            $asinList = implode(',', $asinList);
        }

        $params = array(
            'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
            'ResponseGroup' => 'ItemAttributes,Offers,Images',
            'ReviewSort' => '-OverallRating',
            'ItemId' => $asinList,
            'MerchantId' => ($onlyFromAmazon == true) ? 'Amazon' : 'All'
        );

        return $this->MakeAndParseRequest($params,$itemPage,true);
    }

    public function GetErrors() {
        return $this->mErrors;
    }

    private function AddError($error) {
        array_push($this->mErrors, $error);
    }
    public function FetchItems($params,$itemPage,$maxPrice,$lookup=false)
    {
        $signedUrl = $this->urlBuilder->generate($params);
            if($lookup)
            {
                try 
                {
                    $request = new CurlHttpRequest();
                    $response = $request->execute($signedUrl);
                    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $response);
                    $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
                    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
                    $json = json_encode($simpleXml);
                    $decodedJson=json_decode($json,true);


                        //print_r($decodedJson);
                    print_r($decodedJson);
                    die();
                    $parsedXml = simplexml_load_string($response);

                    if ($parsedXml === false) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return $this->dataTransformer->execute($parsedXml);
                } catch(\Exception $error) {
                $this->AddError("Error downloading data : $signedUrl : " . $error->getMessage());
                return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try 
                {
                    $request = new CurlHttpRequest();
                    $response = $request->execute($signedUrl);
                    $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $response);
                    $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
                    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
                    $json = json_encode($simpleXml);
                    $decodedJson=json_decode($json,true);
                    //print_r($decodedJson);
                    //die();
                    if(isset($decodedJson['Items']))
                    {
                        $this->perRequest=0;
                        foreach($decodedJson['Items']['Item'] as $itm)
                        {
                            if(isset($itm['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice']))
                            {
                                $this->item=$this->item+1;
                                $this->perRequest=$this->perRequest+1;

                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($itm['ItemAttributes']['Title']))
                                                echo $itm['ItemAttributes']['Title'];
                                            else 
                                                echo "N/A";
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($itm['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice']))
                                                echo $itm['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice'];
                                            else 
                                                echo "N/A";
                                        ?>                          
                                    </td>
                                    <?php
                                        $savedAmount=0;
                                        if(isset($itm['Offers']['Offer']['OfferListing']['Price']['FormattedPrice']))
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                                <td><?php echo $itm['Offers']['Offer']['OfferListing']['Price']['FormattedPrice']; ?></td>
                                            <?php
                                            if(isset($itm['Offers']['Offer']['OfferListing']['SalePrice']['FormattedPrice']))
                                            {
                                                $total=(int)($itm['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['Amount']);
                                                $offer=(int)($itm['Offers']['Offer']['OfferListing']['SalePrice']['Amount']);
                                                $savedAmount=$total-$offer;
                                                $savedAmount=$savedAmount/100;
                                                $savedAmount=$this->IND_money_format($savedAmount);
                                                $savedAmount="INR ".$savedAmount.".00";
                                                ?>
                                                    <td><?php echo $itm['Offers']['Offer']['OfferListing']['SalePrice']['FormattedPrice']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?php echo $savedAmount; ?></td>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                $total=(int)($itm['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['Amount']);
                                                $offer=(int)($itm['Offers']['Offer']['OfferListing']['Price']['Amount']);
                                                $savedAmount=$total-$offer;
                                                $savedAmount=$savedAmount/100;
                                                $savedAmount=$this->IND_money_format($savedAmount);
                                                $savedAmount="INR ".$savedAmount.".00";
                                                ?>
                                                <td><?php echo $itm['Offers']['Offer']['OfferListing']['Price']['FormattedPrice']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $savedAmount; ?></td>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else if(isset($itm['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice']))
                                        {
                                            $total=(int)($itm['ListPrice']['Amount']);
                                            $offer=(int)($itm['Offers']['Offer']['OfferListing']['SalePrice']['Amount']);
                                            $savedAmount=$total-$offer;
                                            $savedAmount=$savedAmount/100;
                                            $savedAmount=$this->IND_money_format($savedAmount);
                                                $savedAmount="INR ".$savedAmount.".00";
                                            ?>
                                                <td><?php echo $itm['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $itm['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $savedAmount; ?></td>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                                <td>N/A</td>
                                                <td>N/A</td>
                                                <td>N/A</td>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>  
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($itm['ItemAttributes']['Brand']))
                                                echo $itm['ItemAttributes']['Brand'];
                                            else 
                                                echo "N/A";
                                        ?>                      
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($itm['ItemAttributes']['Size']))
                                                echo $itm['ItemAttributes']['Size'];
                                            else 
                                                echo "N/A";
                                        ?>                      
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($itm['ItemAttributes']['Color']))
                                                echo $itm['ItemAttributes']['Color'];
                                            else 
                                                echo "N/A";
                                        ?>              
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($itm['ItemAttributes']['Manufacturer']))
                                                echo $itm['ItemAttributes']['Manufacturer'];
                                            else 
                                                echo "N/A";
                                        ?>                              
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php

                            }
                        }
                        //return 
                        //echo $maxPrice." : ".$decodedJson['Items']['TotalPages']."<br/>";
                    }
                    //echo "PerRequest : ".$this->perRequest."<br/>";
                    //die();
                    //$parsedXml = simplexml_load_string($response);

                    //if ($parsedXml === false) {
                    //  return false;
                    //}

                    //return $this->dataTransformer->execute($parsedXml);
                } catch(\Exception $error) {
                $this->AddError("Error downloading data : $signedUrl : " . $error->getMessage());
                return false;
                }
            }
    }
    private function MakeAndParseRequest($params,$itemPage,$lookup=false) 
    {
        $this->item=0;

                /*$style="";
                for($looper=1;$looper<=$totalPages;$looper++)
                {
                    if($looper>($itemPage-3) && $looper<($itemPage+3))
                    {
                        if($looper==$itemPage)
                        {
                            $style="style='color:red;'";
                            echo "<a href='examples.php?itemPage=".$looper."' ".$style.">".$looper."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "<a href='examples.php?itemPage=".$looper."'>".$looper."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                        }
                    }else if($looper>($totalPages-3))
                    {

                        echo "<a href='examples.php?itemPage=".$looper."'>".$looper."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }else if($looper>(($totalPages/2)-3) && $looper<(($totalPages/2)+3))
                    {

                        echo "<a href='examples.php?itemPage=".$looper."'>".$looper."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    }
                }
                */
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just Change the Price Range and get how much you want

Comment: You can get API from https://github.com/MarcL/AmazonProductAPI
and make changes to Amazon.php file as mentioned above this is totally work around.