# Amazon Advertising API - Get bestsellers for all categories

Tags: api, amazon-advertising-api

How can I create a url which returns the name of the best sellers (top 100) of all product categories in amazon?

Comment: Have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931144/amazon-ecs-api-to-fetch-1000-top-selling-books

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use the API for this.  The top sellers can be found at the following url:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers
```

As far as I know, the API is not really designed with this in mind.  You can, however, use the  `BrowseNodes` response group in an `ItemLookup` request to get the `BrowseNodeId`(s) of an item.  Then you could use one of the returned `BrowseNodeId` to perform a `BrowseNodeLookup` with the `TopSellers` request parameter to get the top 10 items in that category.

That doesn't really sound like what you're looking for but I thought I'd mention it anyways.

Comment: hey Jonathan, thanks for your answer! I read in the api developer guide that it is really possible to get the best seller of most wished products in amazon. so it should give a better then yours.

Comment: Could you give me a link to the section of the docs that states this?

Comment: its all in the section "Moving Customers to Buy" and the top sellers on page 121

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not see anything in that section of the documentation that specified how to get the "best seller of most wished products".  What I did see in that section is what I've described in my answer.  Without a refinement of your question, I'm afraid I can't help any more than I have.